# Only 2 digits in exponent in scientific ofstream

Tags: c++, scientific-notation

So according to cplusplus.com when you set the format flag of an output stream to scientific notation via

`of.setf(ios::scientific)`

you should see 3 digits plus and a sign in the exponent.  However, I only seem to get 2 in my output.  Any ideas?  Compiled on Mac OS using GCC 4.0.1.

Here's the actual code I am using:

```
of.setf(ios::scientific);
of.precision(6);
for (int i=0;i<dims[0];++i) {
    for (int j=0;j<dims[1];++j) {
    of << setw(15) << data[i*dims[1]+j];                    
    }
    of << endl;
}
```

and an example line of output:

```
   1.015037e+00   1.015037e+00   1.395640e-06  -1.119544e-06  -8.333264e-07
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe cplusplus.com is incorrect, or at least is documenting a particular implementation - I can't see any other online docs which specifically state the number of exponent digits which are displayed - I can't even find it in the C++ specification.

*Edit*:

The [C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=n9VEG2Gp5pkC&lpg=PA27&ots=Rdibsm35UV&dq=C%2B%2B%20standard%20library%20specification&pg=PA624#v=onepage&q=two%20concrete%20values&f=false) doesn't explicitly state the number of exponent digits; but all it's examples display two exponent digits.

Answer (score 4):

It's implementation specific.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in M$ implementation AFAIK

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/624b679a4faf03d

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting 3 in MSVC++08 and g++ 4.4.0 with this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

typedef float NumberType;

double generate_number(void)
{
    return static_cast<NumberType>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
}

void print_number(NumberType d)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << d << std::endl;
};

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<NumberType> data;

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data), 10, generate_number);

    // print
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::scientific);
    std::cout.precision(6);
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), print_number);
}
```

You can easily change the number type it uses. It gives me three places with both `float` and `double`, and the standard says nothing on the actual formatting, so I'd go with [mgb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257182/only-2-digits-in-exponent-in-scientific-ofstream/1257266#1257266).

Comment: Same code compiled on OS X/Intel gives two exponent digits - looks pretty conclusive it's simply implementation-dependent.

Comment: @GMan: Always the way on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a thought - since I am printing floats, why would it display 3 exponent values since the max/min exponent is ~38.  I bet if the data array were type double there would be 3.